# comparing 2 char* with different lengths without null terminators

Tags: c, compare, string-length

I am trying to compare the string literal values of two char* of different lengths. They don't have null terminators so I can't use strcmp. How should I determine if they are equal? Is there a method that I could use?

Example code:

```
int main(){
    char* one = "milk";
    char* two = "dalek! Exterminate!";
    char* three = "milk";

    //Compare and check to see if they are equal. one and two would return false but one and three would return true

}
```

Comment: `char* c = "..."` is not well-formed. A string literal has the type `const char*`. What /exactly/ are you trying to do?

Comment: The stings in your example **do** have null terminators (they are implicit in string literals). Are you sure in your real code the strings really don't have null terminators?

Comment: @sth when I do strcmp, I get a segmentation fault:11 . I read somewhere that that means that my char* didn't have null terminators

Comment: I think a string literal and can be used in strcmp without problems. please post an example of cause segfault.

Comment: There can be lots of reasons for a segfault. Determine where exactly it happens (a debugger will tell you) and post the code related to the problematic line of code.

Comment: Shall that be counted strings? Because then you accepted a bad answer...

Comment: ... was a bad answer when you accepted. Now it's good.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun String literals have type `char[]`, and it is well-formed to assign them to a `char *`. See C99 6.4.5#5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use memcmp to compare the strings up to the point where one of them ends.

```
int strcmpNoTerminator ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t str1len, size_t str2len ) {
    // Get the length of the shorter string
    size_t len = str1len < str2len ? str1len : str2len;
    // Compare the strings up until one ends
    int cmp = memcmp(str1, str2, len);
    // If they weren't equal, we've got our result
    // If they are equal and the same length, they matched
    if(cmp != 0 || str1len == str2len) {
        return cmp;
    }
    // If they were equal but one continues on, the shorter string is 
    // lexicographically smaller
    return str1len < str2len ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Note that this is if your char *s are actually not null terminated. In your example code, `one`, `two`, and `three` are null terminated. I'm assuming that your question itself is correct, and not your example. If the example is correct, then your char *s are null terminated and your problem lies elsewhere, in which case we'd need to see more code to help.

Comment: And why is this wrong? He said there are no null terminators, `\0`s shouldn't be an issue. Even if there were null terminators, this should be fine. The only time this should be an issue is if there are random `\0`s littered throughout the string.

Comment: Seemed like a fair assumption, but since the question didn't specify, I'll add in something for it.

Comment: Sorry for not using a proper character literal in my first comment and so removing all ambiguity. Anyway, change it to `memcmp` and all is well.

Comment: Maybe helpful in this context: You can initialize `char` _arrays_ without 0-terminator if you give an explicit length, e.g. `char foo[3] = "foo";`. This may be easier to use in combination with `sizeof` because you don't have to subtract 1 to get the actual size (and you save one byte, yeah).

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to do the length equality check first and avoid the memcmp call altogether when `str1len != str2len`?

Comment: @Dan Only if you're just checking for equality, in which case this function could be a clean one-liner. Assuming you want to mimic the interface of `strcmp`, the `memcmp` call is required even if the lengths match.

Comment: @MikePrecup Ah right, dunno what I was thinking. Thanks for clarifying.